# AND operator in set_block_property

Tags: oracle, oracle10g, oracleforms

I have two fields in oracle forms and want to search data from table

**code for one field:**

```
SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK_NAME', default_where, 'COLUMN_NAME = '||:BLOCK_NAME.FIELD_NAME);
```

How to use `AND` operator in above code for second filed in oracle forms 10g?

Comment: `SET_BLOCK_PROPERTY('BLOCK_NAME',default_where,'COLUMN_NAME = '||:BLOCK_NAME.FIELD_NAME || ' AND OTHER_COLUMN_NAME = ' || :BLOCK_NAME.OTHER_FIELD_NAME);`.  But your construct looks odd.  Oracle Forms has built-in "query by example" functionality that is looks like you are trying to re-invent / duplicate?